# Number of branchings on {1,...,n}

Tags: graph-theory

A branching is a digraph G, such that the indegree of every vertex is at most 1 and the underlying undirected Graph has no cycles. Show that there are $(n+1)^{n-1}$ branchings on the set of vertices $\{1,...,n\}$.

My ideas: proof by induction seems to be the wrong choice here, since I'm having trouble counting the number of ways to incorporate the n-th vertex into the existing branches in the induction step. I think one can prove it using the Kirchhoffs theorem but I am not allowed to use that.

I don't want a full solution, I prefer tips that push me in the right direction.

Comment: I get that you mean the number of the trees on the set {$1,...,n$}. In fact the number is $n^{n-2}$ if the set is {$1,...,n$} and $(n+1)^{n-1}$ if the set is {$0,1,...,n$}. To prove this let $A_n$ be the set of trees from the vetrices {$1,...,n$} and $B_n$ the set of sequences $(a_1,a_2,...,a_{n-2})$ with elements from {$1,...,n$}. We have that #$B_n=n^{n-2}$ and then we have to find a 1-1 map from $A_n->B_n$

Comment: @Dimitris: branchings are not necessarily trees. Isolated vertices are allowed. But you gave me another idea: If we add a vertex $r$ to $G$ and connect it to all roots $v_i$ of the trees in the branching by adding the edge $(r,v_i)$, then $G$ turns into a tree. And according to your formula we would have $(n+1)^{n-1}$ of possible trees on $\{1,...,n,r\}$. If we remove $r$ again we see that we have $(n+1)^{n-1}$ possible branchings on $G$.

Comment: correct:).i just didn't know what a branch is:P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $M=\{1,...,n\}$. Suppose we add a vertex $r$ to $M$ (let's call the new graph $G$) and connect it to all $v\in M$ using the edge $(r,v)$. All possible trees on $G$ have $r$ as the root. Since we have $n+1$ vertices we know that there are $(n+1)^{n-1}$ possible trees on G. If we remove $r$ again, we see that we now have all possible branchings on $M$. Therefore there are $(n+1)^{n-1}$ branchings on $M$.